# ASP.net MVC wont deserialize a class in http post

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this controller:

```
public JsonResult Register(string step , GlobalOnBoardingDataModel data){}
```

the MVC wont deserialize the `data` variable. 
The `step` variable is getting the post var into it.

I have other classes that are been deserialized fine, but this one won't.
this is the class:

```
public class GlobalOnBoardingDataModel : BaseStepDataModel
    {
        public string Email = string.Empty;
        public string FirstName = string.Empty;
        public string LastName = string.Empty;
        public string PhoneAreaCode = string.Empty;
        public string PhoneCountryCode = string.Empty;
        public string PhoneNumber = string.Empty;
        public string CountryShortName = string.Empty;
        public string AccountCurrency = string.Empty;
        public float InitialDepositAmount = 0;
        public string Address = string.Empty;
        public string City = string.Empty;
        public string State = string.Empty;
        public string DateOfBirth = string.Empty;
        public string CreditCardNumber = string.Empty;
        public string CreditCardExperationDate = string.Empty;
        public bool RiskDisclosure = false;
        public bool Beneficiary = false;
        public string CVVNumber = string.Empty;
        public bool Subscribe = false;
    }
```

BTW, The location of the var is not an issue, seccond place working with other cases.

**Edit**
these are the values (from chrome):

```
step:one
FirstName:kjh
LastName:
CountryShortName:IL
PhoneNumber:
PhoneAreaCode:
PhoneCountryCode:
Email:Test@test.com
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you use Fiddler2 (http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or similar to include the body of the HTTP POST please?

Comment: What is the data that gets posted or set to the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the post body is correct; you need to rewrite the fields and turn them in to `public get/set` properties.

MVC won't model bind to fields.

Since you wish to have non-default defaults for your members; you can use a default ctor to set the property defaults on construction; although I would prefer the approach that doesn't use auto-implemented properties instead:

```
private string _email = string.Empty; 
public string Email { get { return _email; } set { _email = value } }
```

In reality, I suppose there's little difference at runtime - but if you use the constructor approach it's very easy to forget adding a new default to it when adding a new property.

MVC won't bind to fields ultimately because it uses the `System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor` class, in a round-about way, to get the metadata used to identify model properties that are to be bound.  This isn't a bug, though, it's by design and is a good design choice as it enables mechanisms other than reflection the ability to be used in describing model types.

Comment: Thanks, so how do i set default value to avoid null exception? through the constructor?

Comment: Use an explicit backer: `private string _email = string.Empty; public string Email { get { return _email; } set { _email = value } }`